# C++ STL Map : Map.count(element) takes less time than Map[element]

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I was trying this problem on leetcode,

https://leetcode.com/problems/naming-a-company/description/ .

I've observed the following

My Code :

```
long long distinctNames(vector<string>& ideas) {
        unordered_map<string,bool> isPresent;
        vector<vector<long long>> dp(26,vector<long long>(26,0));
        int n = ideas.size();
        long long ans = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        isPresent[ideas[i]] = true;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            char x = ideas[i][0];
            string ts = ideas[i];
            
            for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
            {    
                char y = 'a' + j;
                ts[0] = y;
                if(!isPresent[ts])
                    dp[x-'a'][j]++;
            }
            
        }
        
    
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
            {
                if(i==j) continue;
                ans += (dp[i][j] * dp[j][i]);
            }
        }
        
        return ans;
        
    }
```

This code was getting TLE (85/89).

But, in the same code, if I replace

```
!isPresent[ts]
```

with

```
!isPresent.count(ts)
```

Same code runs much faster and passes.

Anyone can explain why ?

Comment: Do you know what `operator[]` does when a key is not found?  Second, this is why using sites such as Leetcode to learn C++ programming is a waste of time.  Those sites have questions that assume you know the computer language you will be using well-enough to never have to ask basic C++ questions, such as what `[]` does in a map.  Leetcode is not designed to teach C++.

Comment: They don't do the same. `[]` always inserts a new entry if none is found and value-initializes it. There is no point in using a map here. Just use `std::unordered_set<std::string>` instead. That's what it is for.

Comment: Also, your program using `[]` is not the same as the one that uses `count`.  The reason for the time out error is more than likely due to inserting items into the map using `[]` that you were not aware of.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for pointing out answer. Actually, I was doing Leetcode purely for CP and DSA purpose. I felt comfortable with C++ STL so I'm using it for doing problems. However, I don't know C++ much. Surely, I'd love to learn more so that I'm more aware about it but many resources as such on internet don't go as much deep to cover topics like one I asked in the question e.g on many of such sites  [] operator is used for accessing elements, only that part is explained and not that a new entry is created if key is not present. If you have any suggestions of good site, please let me know.

Comment: @DigvijaysinghGour [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at), my preferred source, mentions this behavior. [cplusplus.com](https://cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]/) also mentions this behavior. It does look like there are some sources with lower-quality information about the container, but this is why we recommend looking at good books and high-quality reference sites instead of random tutorials and competitive programming exercises.

Comment: @DigvijaysinghGour `DSA` -- Maybe that's why I see a lot of persons tag "dsa" when the question has nothing to do with digital signature algorithms.  I have not heard of the `DSA` you're referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isPresent[ts]` returns a *reference* to a map value object (so you can write `isPresent[ts] = something`. So if `ts` is not present in the map, then  `isPresent[ts]` must default construct a map entry so that it has something to return a reference to. This is the reason that `map::operator[]` is not const.

`isPresent.count(ts)` has no such problems. If the `ts` key is not present then the map is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

`operator[]` on `std::unordered_map` *inserts* a default constructed element if none is yet present (which is also why the operator doesn't work on a `const` object.) Insertion potentially requires allocating memory or other somewhat slow things. Calling `count` does not, nor would e.g. `find`.